# Bayesian model validation LOOCV

Tags: regression, logistic, bayesian, cross-validation, stan

I am fitting a Bayesian logistic regression using Stan in R. My model will be used for **drawing inference** rather than prediction. My dataset is very small (around 50 observations) so I am planning on using leave-one-out cross validation to check the model. 
My current plan is to fit the model on **all** data points and then assess the model fit separately using accuracy from LOOCV. This way I can draw inference from a version of my model fitted on all data points. 
Does it make sense to check the model like this?

Comment: Are you comparing multiple models fit on the same data? LOO-CV will give an information criterion and is a measure of relative fit, not absolute fit (i.e., whether one model is preferable to another fit on the same data, not whether your model is "right" or "good"). You can use LOO-CV to "adjust" some it measures. For example, in rstanarm and brms you can get a Bayesian R2 based on LOO-CV. Bayesian model fit is often done with posterior predictive checks to make sure that your model's estimates are reasonable approximations of the raw data

Comment: I'm trying to get a measure for the "absolute fit" rather than comparing models. Thanks

Comment: In that case, you should look into what posterior predictive checks you'll want to do. I would recommend looking at posterior predictive p-values: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/ppc_understand2.pdf. As mentioned, there's also the Bayesian R2 that can be used to summarize how accurate the model is for predicting out-of-sample observations.